# how to migrate docker private registry to a new server

Tags: docker, private

I have a private registry with lots of tags/images in the registry.   What is the procedure to migrate the contents of the old private Docker registry from one server to a new one and retain all history and data?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can install the private registry as a a set of services (and then backup their data files and restart them on the destination server), or as a container, with its own way to persist information (I.e. a directory on disk) that you can copy to the new server and launch the container there with the same parameters.